# Azure Storage Account New Directory Creation issue

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-private-link

I am trying to create a new directory inside the azure storage account that we just created, but facing below issue

> Failed to add directory 'member_import'. Error: AuthorizationFailure: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
> RequestId:505c00b0-c01f-000a-6096-23ce2b000000
> Time:2023-11-30T14:07:56.8235722Z

I am facing similar issue while deleting the blobs but I am able to upload the blob without any issues.

Below are the few config related details,

1. This storage account is with Hierarchical namespace - Enabled.
2. It is accessible only through Private link. Created Private end point for targeted sub-resource as blob. We use the same config in another subscription, it was working same. But I also tried by updating it to dfs, I am not able to view anything inside container itself with error 'not accessible'.

Update:
When I set storage account to enable from all networks, I am able to create directories. But our storage account has to be setup privately.

Please let me know what I am using, what should be updated to make it working.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially, I got the same error when I tried to create a directory from the Azure virtual machine with configured target subresource (**`Blob`**) private endpoints.

**Portal:**

[image]

> This storage account is with Hierarchical namespace - Enabled.

For enabled Hierarchical namespace storage you need to create a private endpoint and configure the target sub-resource with **`dfs`** like below:

**Portal:**

[image]

I used the both **`blob`** and **`dfs`** target sub-resources connected private endpoints with Azure storage.

**Portal:**

[image]

After connecting both private endpoints, I can able to create a directory successfully through the Azure virtual machine via RDP.

**Portal:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[Use private endpoints - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-private-endpoints#dns-changes-for-private-endpoints)